# Custom Music in Skyrim's Creation Kit?

Tags: music, modding, skyrim-modding

Can you bring in external music such as mp3s?  If so, how?  I didn't see anything about this in the wiki Bethesda released.

Also how does this work with regards to the Steam Workshop?  Don't imagine they would appreciate uploading copyrighted content.  I don't particularly care about making a public mod, I just want to screw around privately and create dungeons/towns using music from some of my favorite games.

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't really about game development, I'm sure it would get better exposure in the gaming.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @MattJensen Funny, I originally posted it there and they hounded me like a pack of wolves and explicitly told me to go to GameDev.  I deleted the question so it's not there anymore, but anyway, here we are...

Comment: That is is funny, I think most of them just didn't want to deal with the question, because it has very little to do with game development and a lot to do with modding/playing an existing game.

Comment: Modding questions are considered on-topic here.

Comment: ^^ I stand corrected. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm currently having trouble getting my custom music to play, but it worked for someone else so...

1. Convert your MP3s to WAV format and create a folder named "Music" in Skyrim's Data folder. Put your WAVs in there or in any subfolders.
2. Open up the CK and go to Audio > Music Tracks. Right click any entry and click "New". Enter a name in the ID field and select "Single Track" from the dropdown list. Now click "Choose File" and you'll be in the Music folder you just created. Select the desired WAV. If your music will play in battles, make sure you also choose a file that plays when combat ends, and choose some points in the combat music for it to play (in [minute]:[second] format). There should already be some files for finishing music, but you might want to add some that fits your track. I'm not sure what happens if you don't do this. Also, if you want just your custom made locations to have the music, you can click the "Has Conditions" checkbox and set conditions on the Conditions tab.
3. Go to Audio > Audio Types, right-click the category you want to add the new music to, and click Edit. Right click the list of tracks the audio type is using, click Add, and find the track you just added. Save the mod and make sure it's activated.

As I said before, I'm still trying to get my custom music to work. I used Switch Sound File Converter to convert my MP3s, so if you use something else and it works for you, then by all means report back.

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time to answer!  I was afraid this was just going to get buried.  I'm definitely going to give that a try tonight!

Comment: Just to follow up on this, I found this thread which discusses this in depth.  Since your answer put me on the right track, I'll mark it as answer.  But I'm encountering all sorts of bugs and crashes, as are a lot of other people in that thread.  Still haven't been able to get a custom song in the game, but this is definitely on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Skyrim doesn't want to read anything other than 16Bit Mono .Wav files.
I save everything at 44.100Khz.

Does having an Xwm file in your music folder make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

I just copied the papyrus script of a Dragon fight music, inserted my new song in there (replacing the old one by renaming it exactly the same) and pasted the papyrus script.

All done in the CK :)